# Calculate the Displacement of Scrollview while user scrolling

Tags: android, scrollview, onfling

I'm using GustureListner for a scrollview.

In that I have to calculate how many pixel that scrollview is moved during fling event.

I can get velocity and fling start and end position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to do is  `extends SimpleOnGestureListener` to your OnTouchListener class,
so you can override `onFling` and  `onScroll`.
 Refer this [GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html)

Comment: Ya i got it.Thank you,before i implement onFling only.now i use onScroll to get scrolled distance directly.